# Self-hosted Owin NancyFx service with Windows Authentication example?

Tags: owin, ntlm, nancy, self-hosting

I'm trying to setup a service on NancyFx with Owin-self-hosting and Windows Authentication. I have followed some examples but still get the Basic Auth login-prompt when trying to access the service within the same domain. Is there any other examples out there that actually works? Or am I doing it wrong? Missing something?

Here's some of the code:

```
public class Startup
  {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
      var listener = (HttpListener)app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
      listener.AuthenticationSchemes = 
         AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
      app.UseNancy();
    }
  }

public static void RequiresWindowsAuthentication(this NancyModule module)
    {
      module.Before.AddItemToEndOfPipeline(
          new PipelineItem<Func<NancyContext, Response>>(
              "RequiresWindowsAuthentication",
              context =>
              {
                try
                {
                  var env = ((IDictionary<string, object>)context.Items[Nancy.Owin.NancyMiddleware.RequestEnvironmentKey]);
                  var principal = (ClaimsPrincipal)env["server.User"];
                  if (principal == null || principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false) throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
                  context.CurrentUser = new BasicUserIdentity {
                    UserName = principal.Identity.Name,
                    Claims = principal.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role").Select(x => x.Value)
                  };

                  return null;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                  return HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                }
              }));
    }

  public class IndexModule : NancyModule
  {
    public IndexModule(IIndexService indexService)
    {
      this.RequiresWindowsAuthentication();

      Get["/secure"] = _ =>
      {
        return Context.CurrentUser.UserName;
      };
    }
  }
```

Comment: How are you running the self host? Visual Studio? Wheres your app started? You've only shown your setup, but not your other code which starts the web server. Are you running VS as admin? If you're installing the service are you running it under local system?